# Submitting jobs in bash; holding before submitting next job

Tags: bash

I need to submit a large number of jobs, and I have a simple bash script written for that purpose. 
My bash script looks like the following:

```
for i in {1..2}
do
mkdir "Pris_$i"
cp script.sh precip.in Zope* ./"Pris_$i"
cd ./"Pris_$i"
sed -i "s/0.505\*1/0.505\*$i/g" ./precip.in
qsub script.sh
cd ..
done
```

I now want to know a way to control the submission of the jobs: hold till the submitted job finishes and then submit the next job. I could add a dependency by using `qsub -W depend=afterok:jobID <jobname>`, but I need to extract the job ID of the just-submitted job. The output of my qsub looks like: `<jobID>.serveraddress.edu`. Now, how could I extract this jobID?

Comment: @FredrikPihl How will that help? Batch jobs are not run as children of the shell, so it can't wait for them.

Comment: @FredrikPihl I tried 'wait'; like Barmar pointed out, it did not work.

Comment: If it is possible to extract the ID of the previous job from the output of the previous `qsub` command, it will be possible to use the `afterany:` method you have mentioned. In order to help more, we need to see what the output looks like and which part is the ID. Please edit your question to provide these details.

Comment: @TomFenech Yes, my output of qsub looks like: `<jobID>.someserver.edu`. So how could I extract this jobID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this to delay the start of the second job until the first job has finished:

```
job_id=$(qsub first_job | awk -F. '{print $1}')
qsub -W depend=afterok:"$job_id" second_job
```

This approach simply uses awk to split the output of the `qsub` command into fields separated by the `.`. The first field is saved to the variable `job_id`.

To do this within a loop, you could change your loop to something like this:

```
for i in {1..2}; do
    mkdir "Pris_$i"
    cp script.sh precip.in Zope* ./"Pris_$i"
    cd ./"Pris_$i"
    sed -i "s/0.505\*1/0.505\*$i/g" ./precip.in
    if [[ -n "$job_id" ]]; then
        job_id=$(qsub -W depend=afterok:"$job_id" script.sh | awk -F. '{print $1}')
    else
        job_id=$(qsub script.sh | awk -F. '{print $1}')
    fi
    cd ..
done
```

The `if` check takes care of the first iteration, where no previous `$job_id` is defined. For a simple delimiter such as a `.`, it would also be possible to use `cut -d. -f1` to get the ID, instead of the awk command.

Comment: In my case, I'm inside a for loop and my job_names are the same (in different directories, of course), which means that at present I just have one `qsub <jobname>` command.

Comment: I have edited my answer so that it is based on the updated code in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. But it doesn't seem to work. Both the jobs start running together.

Comment: It is possible that `afterany` isn't working as you expect, or that the `$job_id` is not being extracted correctly. I would recommend adding `set -x` to your script to make sure that everything is as you expect.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my command for defining the dependency was wrong. It's working now! I'll make the necessary edits.